# Issues Knitting RMarkdown due to KableExtra After Updating R

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I updated R to version 4.3.1 yesterday and, ever since, have been unable to knit any RMarkdowns to html that use kable. I get the same error message any time I try:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76lGt.png)

Things I have tried to resolve the issue:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling kableExtra

```
remove.packages("kableExtra")
devtools::install_github("kupietz/kableExtra")
library(kableExtra)
```

The installation step runs well until it outputs the following error: **Warning: package ‘kableExtra’ is in use and will not be installed**. However, I am able to run the library(kableExtra) without issue. But when I try to use the kable function, I get this error: **Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :no lines available in input**. The code ran just fine prior to updating R.

2. Updating all packages
3. Restarting R and/or restarting my computer and retrying 1 and 2 together, alone, and in different orders

I am able to knit RMarkdown just fine if I remove all kable code.

I am hoping to be able to knit RMarkdowns with kable code once again.

Comment: Hi, try to avoid using images for warning it is better to paste the warning as a code chunk. Further try to expand your question with information about your OS, etc. I would probably try to reinstall R...

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates a bug in `kableExtra`.

In the image you posted (which would be better as text; use cut and paste to put it in your question), there's a test shown which comes from the `kableExtra` initialization code:

```
  if (!is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) &&
      rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% c(
        "ioslides_presentation", "slidy_presentation",
        "gitbook", "bookdown::gitbook", "radix_article", "radix::radix_article",
        "distill_article", "distill::distill_article"
      )) {
```

It appears that it is testing `rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% c( .... )` with a long list
of possibilities.  Clearly the `kableExtra` author assumes that there will always be only one entry in `rmarkdown::metadata$output`, but in fact you can have several.  For example, this is perfectly legal as the `output` entry in the YAML header:

```
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
```

and it would give two entries in `rmarkdown::metadata$output`.  In general, only the first entry is used, but it's not always a text string, so that section of code is just plain wrong.

To work around this problem, you just need to make sure you only have one output format in the YAML header.